# How to calculate H264 Macroblock length using Ldecod similar to how Vega computes it?

Tags: video, h.264, decoder

Has anyone instrumented Ldecod (H264 reference decoder) to calculate Macroblock size?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have, down to the individual macroblock elements (QP, MVs, coeffs, etc).  It was a number of years back so it was based on ldecod JM13.2.

Anyways, here's the area to look into, at least with JM 13.2

in image.c `decode_one_slice()`

```
void decode_one_slice(struct img_par *img,struct inp_par *inp)
{
  .
  .
  .
  .
  // added mb_start_bits, mb_end_bits, and mb_bits[] to dec_picture (StorablePicture)
  while (end_of_slice == FALSE) // loop over macroblocks
  {
      start_macroblock(&currMB, img, img->current_mb_nr);
      if (active_pps->entropy_coding_mode_flag)
      {
          //save start bit count
          dec_picture->mb_start_bits = img->currentSlice->partArr[0].bitstream->read_len*8 - img->currentSlice->partArr[0].de_cabac.DbitsLeft+1;
      }
      else
      {
          dec_picture->mb_start_bits = img->currentSlice->partArr[0].bitstream->frame_bitoffset;
      }
      .
      .
      .
      .
      //then at bottom of MB loop
      if (active_pps->entropy_coding_mode_flag)
          dec_picture->mb_end_bits = img->currentSlice->partArr[0].bitstream->read_len*8 - img->currentSlice->partArr[0].de_cabac.DbitsLeft+1;
      else
          dec_picture->mb_end_bits = img->currentSlice->partArr[0].bitstream->frame_bitoffset;

      dec_picture->mb_bits[img->current_mb_nr] = dec_picture->mb_end_bits-dec_picture->mb_start_bits;
  }
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Hope that helps, like I said, I haven't looked at the most recent JM decoder so many of these things could have changed but it actually may be easier for you to use a version even earlier than JM 13.2 if you aren't using high profile or FRExt, the earlier code bases were much less complicated.